# how can i use function with args in python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import requests
import tkinter as tk
import json

url = ("https://bankofgeorgia.ge/api/currencies/getSpecialRates")

def convert(from_currency, to_currency, amount): 
    #FORGEL
    if from_currency == "GEL":
        amount = amount / Rates[to_currency]
        amount = round(amount,2)
    elif to_currency == "GEL":
        amount = amount * Rates[from_currency]      
    #FORGEL

    else:    
        amount = amount / Rates[to_currency]
        amount = round(amount * Rates[from_currency], 2) 


    ss.configure(text=amount)
    return amount

Rates = {}

data= requests.get(url).json()
currencies = data['data']
for x in currencies:
    currency = x['currency']
    rateSell = x['rateSell']
    Rates.update({currency:rateSell})
    
window = tk.Tk()

FromL = tk.Label(text="From")
FromE = tk.Entry()
FromG = FromE.get()

ToL = tk.Label(text="To")
ToE = tk.Entry()
ToG = ToE.get()

AmoutL = tk.Label(text="Amout")
AmoutE = tk.Entry()
AmoutG = AmoutE.get()


ss = tk.Label(text="0")

widget = tk.Button(window, text="Calculate", command=lambda:convert(FromG,ToG,AmoutG))


FromL.pack()
FromE.pack()

ToL.pack()
ToE.pack()

AmoutL.pack()
AmoutE.pack()

ss.pack()

widget.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

i made currency calculator in console and it was working well, but I wanted to make app for it so I used tkinter for it. user must put from which currency he wants to calculate and then amount and press button to calculate but I cant get user inputs from app to calculate.

Comment: Look at your code: `FromE = tk.Entry(); FromG = FromE.get()`. As soon as you create the entry you try getting the data out of it. That isn't how GUIs are supposed to work. You need to leave some time for the user to input data into the entry. I suggest changing the `lambda:convert(FromG,ToG,AmoutG)` to `lambda: convert(FromE.get(), ToE.get(), AmoutE.get())`

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is for the function tied to the button fetch the data it needs, rather than trying to have the button pass the information in. It makes the code much easier to understand and to debug. You can still pass parameters to the function that does the calculation if you wish.

```
def calculate():
    FromG = FromE.get()
    ToG = ToE.get()
    AmoutG = AmoutE.get()
    convert(FromG, ToG, AmoutG)
...
widget = tk.Button(window, text="Calculate", command=calculate)
```